# `git stash --patch` doesn't accept 'enter'

Tags: git

I'm having troubles with using `git stash --patch`,

when I run it I get the first modified file, and the prompt:

```
Stash this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]?
```

I can then type the letters, but they just get printed, and if I hit enter, I just see a `^M` printed for each enter I type, like this:

```
 Stash this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]? d^M?^M^M^M^M
```

any clues how to fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: Is it Git Bash or some other command line? Windows?

Comment: it's under zsh on mac,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with adding the server key of a new SSH server, it turns out that the language setting of my keyboard was wrong,

I added

export LC_ALL=C

and restarted the zsh session, which solved.